# My DragTarget only receives the image that is listed first. How do I change this?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

Both Images are intended to be dragged into the `leftbox` div. when you drag the blue image, which is listed above the orange image. It successfully drops into the `leftbox`. When you drag the orange image to the droptarget the blue image replaces it once dropped. This is because it is listed above the orange image. I tested this out by swapping the code orders. Putting the orange image first. And the orange image was then the only recipient of the dropping. Any help is appreciated.

```js
function allowdrag(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function Drop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var texts = e.dataTransfer.getData('image/png')
  var data = document.getElementById(texts);
  e.target.appendChild(data)
}

function drog(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('image/png', e.target.id)
}
```

```css
#leftbox {
  width: 20%;
  height: 175px;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 75px 15px 0px 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

#image1 {
  height: 175px;
  width: 138px;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  display: inline-block
}

#reset {
  height: 0;
  width: 21%;
  padding-bottom: 18%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  background-image: url(https://win-conditions.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/download-1.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="leftbox" ondrop="Drop(event)" ondragover="allowdrag(event)">
  <button id="reset" type="button"></button>
</div>

<div id="image">
  <img id="image1" src="https://win-conditions.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/electrospirit.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drog(event)">
  <img id="image1" src="https://win-conditions.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/fire_spirits-1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drog(event)">
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0h7c45kj/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your images should have different IDs:

```html
<img id="image1" ... >
<img id="image2" ... >
```